# find value of a line equation in R

Tags: r

Here I have a temp line in R like
 `MyLine = abline(lm(tempX~tempY))`
now I want to calculate the value of tempY by using(import) tempX in MyLine function.
how can I do that?

Comment: `abline` draws a line on a base graph, it doesn't return anything - `MyLine` is `NULL` in your example code. You'll need to save the `lm` model as an object to do anything useful.

Comment: But I'm completely confused by what you mean by *"by using(import) tempX in MyLine function."* Could you make a small reproducible example showing sample inputs and also showing the expected result?

Comment: how can i save that?

Comment: `MyModel = lm(tempX ~ tempY)`. By "save" here I mean "assign to a name using `<-` or `=`."

Comment: i mean i have value for x and i want calculate the value of y (in point(x,y)) in Myline.

Comment: `MyModel <- lm(tempX ~ tempY, data = data.frame(tempX, tempY)); predict(MyModel, newdata = data.frame(tempX = ...))`

Comment: `predict(MyModel, newdata = data.frame(tempx = your_new_x_value))`. Of course you can only predict giving new data from the right-hand side of your model formula to get an estimate for the left hand side.